# How to do atomic update counter using dynamodb & c#

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, advertisement-server

i am new to dynamodb and trying to write a counter.I am worried about concurrent access to mycounter.

Any code samples ? Any strategies ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

[Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_DynamoDB_AmazonDynamoDB_UpdateItem.htm)