# Atomic Increment a counter field using DynamoDB in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I want to know how to increment a field in an Amazon DynamoDB table by 1. From my understanding I need to use the `UpdateItem` with Action `ADD` but I wasn't able to do it.

I need an example how to do it in C#. Let's assume a table with `id` as hash and `count` as the counter which is set to 0 when the row is created.

note: the reference to the page on Amazon [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315080/how-to-do-atomic-update-counter-using-dynamodb-c-sharp) id done using the older version, I need a solution using V2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The request you need to construct will look like this:

```
var request = new UpdateItemRequest
{
    TableName = "Table",
    Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
    {
        { "id", new AttributeValue { N = "5" } }
    },
    AttributeUpdates = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValueUpdate>()
    {
        {
            "count",
            new AttributeValueUpdate { Action = "ADD", Value = new AttributeValue { N = "1" } }
        },
    },
};
```